# Sass number precision in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

How can I change the precision of floating point numbers in Sass using the [sass-rails](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails) gem? My compiled Sass stylesheets only give three decimals of precision by default.

Comment: This is not an exact duplicate. The OP of the other question is using Sass with Compass. I can't change Sass source files, since Sass is included in the sass-rails gem. This would break future updates.

Comment: So install the [compass-rails](https://github.com/Compass/compass-rails) gem and use its ability to change that option without having to modify the Sass source. Problem solved.